# How to apply ST_GeomFromText() function to format text when using PostgreSQLCopyHelper (https://github.com/PostgreSQLCopyHelper/PostgreSQLCopyHelper)

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

`INSERT INTO geotable (geometrydata) values (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@geometrydata));`

How can I run the above insert statement to posgresql database using PostgreSQLCopyHelper in c# code. Tried to do something like this.

`var copyHelper = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<GeoData>("geotable ") .Map("geometrydata", x => x.geometrydata, NpgsqlDbType.Geometry);`

geometrydata is a string like below.

```
`var geometrydata = "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-81.800007507357,24.491670214271,0.0],[-81.800007507357,24.500003548802,0.0],[-81.7916741718259,24.500003548802,0.0],[-81.7916741718259,24.491670214271,0.0],[-81.800007507357,24.491670214271,0.0]]]}"`
```

How can I format data using postgis function when using PostgreSQLCopyHelper. (https://github.com/PostgreSQLCopyHelper/PostgreSQLCopyHelper )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call functions while loading data with `COPY`.

If you really need that, you would have to create a view on the table and use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view that inserts a suitable processed row into the table.

It will probably perform better to load the data to a staging table and perform the conversion with an `UPDATE` on all rows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this PostgreSQLCopyHelper plugin is not using COPY command I suppose. Does it? I thought it is a bulk insert helper without using any command.

Comment: The project page says "It wraps the COPY methods from Npgsql behind a nice Fluent API", so I'd be surprised if it used anything else than `COPY` under the hood. And the limitations for the SQL statement should apply to this function.